# Why are there two different values of this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I was doing some limit calculations and met some strange thing.

Here is the question:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\ln(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})}$$

My idea is that since both the denominator and numerator approach zero, l'Hospital's Rule can be applied. Therefore, we have:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\ln(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)}{\frac{d}{dx}[\ln(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})]}$$
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x}{\frac{e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3}}}$$
Then, we can simplify this fraction by moving the denominator of the denominator to the numerator of the whole:
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})}{\frac{2}{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}}$$
Then, divide both numerator and denominator by $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ to give:
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x^\frac{4}{3}(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})}{\frac{2}{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}-\frac{2}{3}}$$
Then, apply l'Hospital's Rule again:
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{8}{3}x^\frac{1}{3}(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})+2x^\frac{4}{3}(e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}})}{\frac{4}{9}e^{\frac{1}{2}{x^\frac{4}{3}}}x^\frac{1}{3}}$$
Then, divide both numerator and denominator by $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ to give:
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\frac{8}{3}(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})+2x(e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}-\frac{2}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}})}{\frac{4}{9}e^{\frac{1}{2}{x^\frac{4}{3}}}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{8}{3}}{\frac{4}{9}}$$
$$=6$$

Well this is the right answer. **However, when I did the calculation in a slightly different way, something strange happened.**

In the step 'divide both numerator and denominator by $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$ to give', if I divide both numerator and denominator by $x$ instead of $x^{-\frac{1}{3}}$, I have:
$$=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2(\int_{0}^{x^\frac{2}{3}}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^2}\,dx+1-x^\frac{2}{3})}{\frac{2}{3}e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{\frac{4}{3}}}{x^{-\frac{4}{3}}}-\frac{2}{3}{x^{-\frac{4}{3}}}}$$
Then, according to this formula, as $x$ approached zero, the numerator approaches 2 and the denominator approaches $0$. **Therefore, in this way, the answer is $\infty$!**

But how could there be different answer? I believe there must be something wrong in my calculation. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, your mistake is in the following statement (when you are dividing by $x$): the denominator converges to $0$. Let's consider the denominator
$$
\frac{2}{3} e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} x^{-4/3} - \frac{2}{3}x^{-4/3} = \frac{2}{3}x^{-4/3}(e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} - 1).
$$
We have a product of two functions $x^{-4/3}$ and $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} - 1$ and, obviously, first one converges to $\infty$ and the second converges to $0$ (as $x \to 0$). We can compute the limit of the product by considering the exact asymptotic behaviour of $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} - 1$. Using Taylor series we can write $e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} - 1 \sim \frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}$. Therefore,
$$
\frac{2}{3} e^{\frac{1}{2}x^{4/3}} x^{-4/3} - \frac{2}{3}x^{-4/3} \sim \frac{2}{3}x^{-4/3} \frac{1}{2}x^{4/3} = \frac{1}{3}.
$$
Thus, in the limit you get the same answer - $6$.

Comment: Ok!  Thank you so much! I got it! :)